# How to make jQuery lighboxes (like fancybox) to display pictures faster?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

At [Officesnapshots.com](http://www.officesnapshots.com/2009/11/17/twitters-latest-office-move-version-3/) I think they are using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) (check the closing button). But the pictures load damn fast. Is it really fancybox or another plugin? If it is fancyboxn how can I archieve the same speed as them?

Answer (score 1):

The images' loading speed has usually nothing to do with the plugin used: The process is a simple `image.src='filename.jpg'` in any case, and the browser does the loading.

I suspect the seemingly faster loading is down to the large window closing and re-opening during the loading process.

They also may have faster servers to deliver the images.

Answer (score 0):

OfficeSnapshots.com is actually using a plug-in called [Highslide JS](http://highslide.com/).  I'd say start with experimenting with that.

Answer (score 0):

The images are preloaded as soon as you visit the homepage - so when you move between slides the image is already in cache.

It seems the plugin handles selecting images from folder or flickr, and the `ajaxCache` property will precache these images.

Looks like a nice plug-in - commercial licence though ...

Answer (score 0):

I run officesnapshots.com and we do use Highslide from highslide.com.  We implement it into the website using the wordpress plugin Highslide JS.  There are different licenses, and for personal website I believe it is free.